# How to draw a text on an image and how to use this image as my custom pin icon?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How to draw a text on an image and how to use this image as my custom pin icon?

I use the official code in the https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/custom-renderer/map/
I can use the custom pin image as an icon to replace the standard google map pin, but I want to add text on this customized pin, then use my new pin (with the text) to my new customized pin icon.

Here is the code I used now

```
 foreach (var pin in customPins)

 {

       var marker = new MarkerOptions ();

       marker.SetPosition (new LatLng (pin.Pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Pin.Position.Longitude));

       marker.SetTitle (pin.Pin.Label);

       marker.SetSnippet (pin.Pin.Address);

       marker.SetIcon (BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource (Resource.Drawable.pin));

  }
```

so the maker SetIcon this method to get custom pin icon on my Rouscoure.Drawable folder. In this folder I stored my pin.png image.
I am struggling to draw text in my original pin image. Then, I also don't know how to use SetIcon or InvokeIcon to load my new image if I succeeded add text on my pin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main idea is to create a canvas first, then create a paint. After that combine those two together.

There are a lot of Java sample when you google it. The only thing you need to do is how to convert it to Xamarin.Android. It should be easy.

Here is the sample: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/236649/#Comment_236649

Comment: Thanks. This is very help!!

Comment: No problem, if you have any question, just let me know.